# p:treeTable sorting reopens closed nodes that were open before

Tags: jsf, primefaces

it seems to be default behaviour, that TreeTable will reopen previously closed nodes when sorting via clicking a header.
See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/sort.xhtml and test it with the following steps:
1) Open and close a node
2) Click on a header to sort by that column
Result: The previously closed node will be reopened.
That is the case for all nodes that have once been opened.

Question is, how can I prevent this? I don't want the nodes to be reopened.

Comment: Sounds like a 'bug' or an omission and related to 'statefulness' being added to the treetable. Not sure if this can be fixed just client-side or needs server-side work to. You could check the client-side js to see if some 'stateful' code does not clean stateful things. Happens to btw for paging https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/paginator.xhtml. Best is to file an issue in github https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: It's my first ever ticket, so I really hope that not going completely 'by the script' will not lead to closing the ticket:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3172

Comment: It's 'perfect'... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

My collegue found a workaround for now:
Use a collapse event in the tree:

```
<p:ajax event="collapse" 
   onstart="someJSMethod()"
   oncomplete="someOtherJSMethod()" />
```

I don't think the Js methods matter, in my case they show a loading indicator. I think using the event matters here.